# R return an error when i run this code and i don't understand the error

Tags: r, error-handling

I have this code

```
getSymbols("^GSPC")
Log_return <- log(GSPC$GSPC.Close/lag(GSPC$GSPC.Close))
ggplot(Log_return, aes(sample = Log_return$GSPC.Close)) + stat_qq()+stat_qq_line(color = "red")
```

and it returns this error

```
Warning messages:
1: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_qq()`). 
2: Computation failed in `stat_qq()`
Caused by error in `coredata<-.zoo`:
! “value” : attempt to assign invalid coredata to zoo object 
3: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_qq_line()`). 
4: Computation failed in `stat_qq_line()`
Caused by error in `coredata<-.zoo`:
! “value” : attempt to assign invalid coredata to zoo object
```

i don't understand what this means, and i have tried searching what a zoo object or coredata is but i can't find anything.

I expected a qq-plot but it gave me an error.

Comment: Instead of including the `Log_return` twice (it is already included as source of data in first argument of `ggplot`) try something like: `ggplot(Log_return, aes(sample = GSPC.Close)...`